# AWS Route 53 Subdomain works intermittently

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53

I have some strange problem with AWS Route 53 subdomain.

My main domain points to an AWS EC2 instance. I created another EC2 instance to host my dev environment. I want to access my test instance from a subdomain.

To do that, I created A records with my elastic EC2 test instance with 1day TTL.

The really strange thing is that sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. 
Just [checkout](https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/dev.tidybear.fr) the global propagation state of my subdomain and refresh the page (without cache) to see it changes every second.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

This site is showing several issues with your DNS setup you should probably investigate further: http://mxtoolbox.com/domain/dev.tidybear.fr/

[image]